# In RSpec2 controller test (with render_views), locate the view instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, internationalization, controller, rspec2

I'm writing a test for missing translation look-ups—and I'm a beginner with RSpec. In other words, I'm writing a specification that, in the view, all visible text is passed through the translate method.

I refer not to missing translations, but to missing translation look-ups (where the source code lacks the call to the #t or #translate method).

To do that, I want to stub the i18n translate method (I18n#t).

In order to do that, how do I find the view instance RSpec2 is using? This view instance includes the module ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper. If I could acquire access to that view object, I could (I think) stub its translate method. BTW, I think I should start from @controller.

Everything else in the spec works in the usual way (including the failing test) except finding and stubbing the view's translate helper method, #t. I am using render_views.

I have tried (in various ways) #helper, #translate and #view. Maybe I'm missing something?

Searching in ObjectSpace (in my test) for all objects with method #translate, I was able to grab the object, because its class is I18n::Backend::Simple. So my spec works, but it would be a lot faster presumably if the code didn't have to search ObjectSpace for it!

As background, by far, the simplest test plan seems to be to loop through the actions for each controller, in an RSpec controller test, and look for visible alphabetical characters. First, one would stub the Rails translate helper to return empty strings. Also, one would strip the tag names, as well as any script and style tags.

My Gemfile includes capybara 1.1.4, capybara-webkit 0.12.1, factory_girl 4.1.0, 
factory_girl_rails 4.1.0, rails 3.2.9, rspec 2.12.0, rspec-rails 2.12.0.

Answer (score 0):

Even after finding the right object, mysteriously RSpec's stubbing (or so I thought) was breaking other tests:

```
before(:each) { object.stub   :translate, true }
after( :each) { object.unstub :translate       }
```

Instead, I successfully used:

- Alias_method_chain on I18n::Backend::Simple's instance method #translate, and
- A Ruby global variable to switch #translate into empty-string mode.

Later I concluded it was likely Formtastic's i18n caching which had been breaking the other tests. To fix this, the right setting (in config/initializers/formtastic.rb) is:

```
Formtastic::FormBuilder.i18n_cache_lookups = ! (Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?)
```

I still haven't found the view instance, though. And that's what I want to know, in the question! So, please give me answers and I will accept one that works.